# Clarification of a convex space

Tags: geometry

Just for be clear: if a convexity space is all set of lines that runs from all different points contained in such space that all can be connected with a line (beeline), does all the set of points in the line needs to pass "inside" the shape for making the affirmation that the inner space of the shape is a convex space?

In the image the shape ABCDE do not accomplish this condition.  As we can see the line R1 connecting a1 with b1 shows that some part of the interval a1b1 do not belongs to the shape ABCDE So, is the shape ABCDE a CONVEX SPACE?

[image: Convex SPACE in shape ABCDE]

Comment: Even though this is already more or less part of your message, the term "space" shall be replaced by "set".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a space where straight lines and segments are defined, a convex subset $Y$ is one in which every segment between two points of $Y$ is *fully contained in $Y$*.

So, this shape would not be convex. You can also try reading [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_space).